# How can I make a Javascript search ignore special characters (accents)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, diacritics

I'm making a contact list that contains institutions' phones and emails. I put each institution into a div (class="container"). On the top of the page, I put a search input:

```
<input type="text" id="textFind">
```

Then I used JQuery to filter the DIVs, according to the input:

```
//makes contains case insensitive
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function(elem) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});

//filters divs
$("#textFind").keyup(function() {
    var stringPesquisa = $(this).val();
    $(".container").hide();
    $('div:contains(' + stringPesquisa + ')').show()
});
```

It's working fine, BUT:

QUESTION 1: I need it to ignore accents (for example: "gerencia" could return "Gerência", "primaria" could return "primária"). I tried many ways to do that, nothing has worked so far. Any ideas?

QUESTION 2: I'm learning Javascript and JQuery, so even the "case insensitive" function is working properly, I just can't understand the code. Could someone explain it?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Not actually, sorry, it's quite confusing for me! I tried to use:
 
$(".container").normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "");

But it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? What exactly did you try? What result did you get? Any errors in the console?

Comment: Also, really, I'm not sure what the `makes contains case insensitive` function does o_o